# Why does clicking a button with two event handlers attached to it results in the page scrolling back to the top?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

In a WordPress page with a CTA button, I attached two click event handlers one of which is to show an element that wraps an Hubspot form while the other one is to scroll to the beginning of the form.

HTML for the button:

```
<a id="btn" class="btn" role="button" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="resetScrollpoint('#contact-form-wrap')" target="<?php echo $link['target']; ?>" title="<?php echo $link['title']; ?>">
    <?php echo $link['title']; ?>
</a>
```

Element that contains the hidden form. Form is by default hidden.

```
  <div id="contact-form-wrap" class="contact-form-wrap" style="display:none;"> <?php echo do_shortcode("$contact"); ?></div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $("#contact-form-wrap").show();
        return false;
    });
});

function resetScrollpoint(selector) {
  if(!selector) return false;
  window.scroll(0,$(selector).offset().top - $('#header').height());
}
```

Please see the image below to see where the problem is in the page [here](https://packedwithpurpose.gifts/gift-concierge/).

[image]

Please note this code works if I remove `style="display:none;` from the element that wraps the form.

Comment: If the element is hidden, its `offset().top` is `0`. You need to show the element before trying to scroll to it, but `resetScrollpoint()` is running first.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but how can I fix it?

Comment: Can I put `resetScrollpoint()` into setTimeOut() to fix it?

Comment: Put everything in a single function so you can control the order. Do it all in the `$("#btn").click()` function.

Comment: I tried putting everything in jQuery(document).ready() but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the call to `resetScrollPoint()` out of the `onclick` attribute, and call it from the jQuery handler. That way you can call it after unhiding the element, so its position is known.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $("#contact-form-wrap").show();
        resetScrollpoint('#contact-form-wrap');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Scrolling is not happening with your answer. Please check it once again

Comment: I pushed your answer live so you can see your code in the page and refine it to fix the issue with scrolling. thanks

Comment: I tried setTimeOut(), but it didn't help. I noticed clicking the button actually is changing the scroll position but in backward position.

Comment: Why do you subtract `$("#header').height()`?

Comment: because it is sticky header.

Comment: I don't think that matters, `offset()` takes that into account.

Comment: Let me try, please give me a minute

Comment: It didn't make any difference to remove $("#header').height() from the expression.

Comment: Then sorry, I don't know.

Comment: I see this error in the console `Uncaught ReferenceError: resetScrollPoint is not defined`. I put the function within `jQuery(document).ready(function ($)` only.

Comment: I mistyped with `P` instead of `p`. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: Perfect, all is fine now. Thanks a lot Barmar. Have a  nice day!

Comment: If you found a solution, you can post it as an answer.

Comment: I accepted yours as a solution because that is what helped fix it.